# __vectorcall and C++ constructors

Tags: c++, windows, constructor, calling-convention

["DirectXMath Library Internals"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article at MSDN says that:

> Because of limitations with __vectorcall, we recommend that you not use GXMVECTOR or HXMVECTOR for C++ constructors.

and

> Because of limitations with __vectorcall, we recommend that you not use XM_CALLCONV for C++ constructors.

, where (when using `__vectorcall`) `GXMVECTOR` and `HXMVECTOR` are `const __m128` or `const __m128&` and `XM_CALLCONV` is `__vectorcall`.

I saw no other places with such recommendations.

If the above limitations really exist, why do they exist? What would happen if I write code like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
    __vectorcall foo(const __m128 a, const __m128 b)
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: These recommendations are specific to writing a library.  You cannot make any assumptions about the compiler that the library user uses.  He'll be dead in the water with GCC, Clang, an older VS version or another language like C#.

Comment: So using MSVC 2013/2015 I can safely ignore such recommendations when writing "simple" applications?